# Ckeditor 4 - How to callback selected file/image in custom browser?

Tags: ckeditor

With Ckeditor3, when implementing your own file/image browser, to send back the file URL back to CKeditor, you would call :

```
window.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(2,filename);
```

But it seems with Ckeditor4 this does not work anymore, even though the [docs](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_browser_api) still says it's working...

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seems like the problem is the "2" hard coded... as mentioned [here](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/7899)

I solved it by using the example 2 function from the docs mentioned in my question

Answer (score 3):

In this line

```
window.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(CKEditorFuncNum,filename);
```

CKEditorFuncNum should be the value sent to the file browser via url param with the same name i.e &CKEditorFuncNum=4 - in this case 4 will be the first argument for callFunction().